# How to set size for each element in Row as the smallest element? (reverse IntrinsicWidth or IntrinsicHeight)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a row with a column and a large image. I need to set the same image height as the height of column.

Example of code:

```
return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(/*Some amount of elements */),
        Image(),
      ],
    );
```

P.S. I don't want to limit size of whole Row, because on different screens, like smartphone or tablet screens, size and elements of Column will different.

P.P.S. In the first picture you can see a rough sketch of the result of my work. A green rectangle indicates an image. As you can see, it is much more than a column with text. In the second figure, I showed what I need to get as a result, provided that the number of elements in the column can change and the size of the image must be adjusted to the size of the column.

[image: [1]]
[image: [1]]

Comment: it doesn't make sense to make an item take a smaller size that the smallest size they can take.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Okay, how would you suggest implementing such layout? I updated the question and added a rough sketch.

Comment: So if the column contain more text and make the column taller then the image's height will have to be tall as column? You can use a Container outside of the column with height is infinity and image then add margin to your container to keep space between container with the edges of the screen if you want

Answer (score 0):

Please try "Expanded" in the place of column, i hope it will help you and manage row height as per data.

Please try and let me know if any concern.....

```
return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(/*Some amount of elements */),
        Image(),
      ],
    );
```